# Konjunktiv II – when to use “wäre”, and when to use “würde”

Tags: subjunctive

I am learning about Konjunktiv II, and there is one thing that is confusing me, and that is when are you supposed to use *wäre*.

Is there some rule, or some logic behind it, when are you supposed to use *wäre*?

Comment: I wonder if the question was about _würde … sein_ rather than just _würde_. Would make more sense than what the only answer assumed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Wäre* is the Konjunktiv for *sein*:

> Ich wäre gerne ein Tiger.

All verbs that use the Hilfsverb *werden* are formed with *würde*:

> Ich würde gehen.

See this [nice overview (German)](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=37).